# Seeking 800M or better resolution Annual Precipitation (at least two different years) raster data for four corner states or the Navajo Nation

Tags: data-request, geospatial, open-source

I was wondering if anyone on here might know where I can find at least 800 meter or better resolution of Average Annual or Average Monthly Precipitation data, that would cover the 4 corners area (UT, AZ, NM, CO) or basically the Navajo Nation?

I am working on a Mule Deer Habitat Suitability analysis and this is the last set of data I need to do a comparison for a school project.

I know PRISM data is at 800m resolution, but it's a 30 year annual average. Is there a way to extract a single year from PRISM?

I've been looking around for a couple weeks now.